# Accessing parameters using registers in 64 bit arch

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system

I have took The Hardware/Software Interface course  by University of Washington.
In that course the lecturer explained about x86-32 vs x86-64.
He showed a simple disassembled function which did a swap.

```
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int t0 = *xp;
    int t1 = *yp;
    *xp = t1;
    *yp = t0;
}
```

In x86-32 I can tell that the parameters are passed throught the stack, however in x86-64 the parameters are passed throught the registers.

I can tell that in x86-32 the parameters are passed in cdecl calling conventions as opposed to x86-64 which is it a fastcall calling conventions.

Why does it happens? Has it always been like that? What happens if I choose to pass more than the number of the registers parameters?

Comment: I thought the use of registers was dependant on the implementation of the compiler used - nothing to do with the OS architecture.

Comment: All of this is not only platform specific, but also very compiler specific, and also depends a lot on optimizations. And if you have more arguments than available registers, then some (or all) may be passed on the stack.

Comment: @suspectus Processor manufacturers usually define conventions that most compiler provider follow, which allows interoperability (linking to a library compiled with a different compiler). Where different conventions exist on given hardware, OS vendors tend to specify a single convention, if only implicitly via the system libraries.

Comment: @Gilles Interesting - thanks the for info.

Comment: @Gilles apart from when they get in wrong as ms did with windowless rtf!!

Answer (score 3):

The x86 processor is much older than x64. The calling convention landscape for x86 grew organically with different operating systems and different compilers choosing different approaches. These days, only these calling conventions are still widely used:

- cdecl
- stdcall
- Borland fastcall
- MS fastcall

But many more calling conventions have been used over the years. As you can imagine, attempting any sort of binary interop is complicated by the existence of many different calling conventions.

When the main operating systems adopted x64, lessons had been learnt. And the OS designers were very keen for there to be a single calling convention as part of a well-specified ABI. This has many advantages. Not only does it make life easier for the developer, but it makes developing compiler tooling easier, and it also makes it easier to secure code.

Interestingly, there are still multiple calling conventions in existence on x64, but on a single platform, there is only ever one x64 calling convention. There is the MS x64 calling convention and the System V x64 calling convention as used by the Unix like operating systems. Both of these x64 calling conventions are fastcall with parameters passed through registers.

> What happens if I choose to pass more than the number of the registers parameters?

In that case, for all calling conventions that I have ever encountered, the parameters are passed on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The calling convention used will depend on your compiler. Default settings among compilers will also vary. cdecl and fastcall are the two most widely adopted calling conventions. fastcall passes the first two arguments in registers, rest on the stack. You can often set the calling convention to use as a compiler flag. Also you can specify the calling convention as a function attribute

```
void __attribute__((cdecl)) swap(int *xp, int *yp);
void __attribute__((fastcall)) swap(int *xp, int *yp);
```

Or even specify that you want the parameters in specific registers:

```
void swap(int *xp asm ("rax"), int *yp asm ("rbx"));
```

In any case the compiler can ignore any of those instructions and/or issue errors/warnings if something is not possible.